# Some doubts related to the use of the BorderLayout object

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I am studying Java Swing and I have a doubt related to the use of the **BorderLayout** object.

I have this simple example program that create a ToolBar:

```
package com.andrea.menu;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ToolBar extends JFrame {

    public ToolBar() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();      // The menu bar containing the main menu voices
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");         // Creo un menu a tendina con etichetta "File" e lo aggiungo
        menubar.add(file);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);                   // Sets the menubar for this frame.

        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));

        JButton exitButton = new JButton(icon);
        toolbar.add(exitButton);
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });

        add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setTitle("Simple toolbar");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ToolBar ex = new ToolBar();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So it create a **JToolBar** object by the line:

```
JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
```

and then it put it in the **NORTH** position of the **BorderLayout** object by the line:

```
add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Reading the documentation I know that:

> A border layout lays out a container, arranging and resizing its
>   components to fit in five regions: north, south, east, west, and
>   center

My doubt is: the `BorderLayout` object whom it refers? At the external **JFrame** container?

It means that it puts the **toolbar** object in the NORTH position of my **JFrame**? Or what?

Comment: Your `Toolbar` **is a** `JFrame`

Answer (score 1):

You put the toolbar in the NORTH position of your `ToolBar` instance named `ex`.

Your `ToolBar` class extends `JFrame`. The `add` method is inherited by `ToolBar` from `JFrame`. In your `main` you call `ToolBar` constructor, which creates a new instance of `ToolBar` and saves the reference to `ex`. It also calls the `initUI` method on `ex`, which calls `add` on `ex`.

Comment: mmm yes I mean that: my ToolBar IS A JFrame (because it extends JFrame) so ToolBar object is a container and I put the JToolBar toolbar object in the north of this container, is it right?

Comment: @AndreaNobili right! They are not added directly to the jframe but to the contentPane since java 5 i think im not sure

Comment: `javax.swing.JFrame`: "As a conveniance `add` and its variants, `remove` and `setLayout` have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary."

Comment: Check this out [ContentPane (or Content Pain?)](http://www.leepoint.net/JavaBasics/gui/gui-commentary/guicom-60-contentpane.html). It's excellent to clarify some doubts IMHO.